# Importar Axios em Mixins VueJS

Tags: vue.js

Tem como eu importar o **Axios no Mixins**? Eu tenho uma Rest API e estou colocando em um **Mixin** meu código de **GET**, mas eu utilizo **Axios** para isso. Quando eu tento importar o **Axios** dentro do **Mixins**, ele me retorna:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import at MyMixins.js:1

**MyMixins.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'

let getMixins = {
    created() {
        axios.get(`https://api.myjson.com/bins/17rqo1`)
            .then(response => {
                console.log( response )
            })
            .catch(e => {
                // Errors
            })
    }
}
```

**List.vue**

```
<template>
   <h1> Test Mixins <h1>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            dataItem: [],
            errors: []
        }),
        mixins: [getListagem]
    }
</script>
```

O que estou fazendo de errado? Eu estou criando **váriavel simples com .js** porque eu não gostaria de usar

```
`import myMixins from ./myMixins`
```

nos meus **.vue**

Tem algum jeito de fazer isso?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro que recebes sobre o `import` creio estar relacionado com a tua versão do Node ou pela falta de compilador (webpack).

De qualquer maneira o que queres fazer é possivel, mas tens de exportar algo no `MyMixins.js`. E tens mesmo de requerir o ficheiro sempre que quiseres adicionar esse mixin.

**MyMixins.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default const getMixins = {
    created() {
        axios.get(`https://api.myjson.com/bins/17rqo1`)
            .then(response => {
                console.log( response )
            })
            .catch(e => {
                // Errors
            })
    }
}
```

**List.vue**

```
<template>
   <h1> Test Mixins <h1>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    import getListagem from './MyMixins'
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            dataItem: [],
            errors: []
        }),
        mixins: [getListagem]
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Então Sergio, assim eu sei que funciona, porque passaria pelo meu webpack, não tem como eu usar um Mixins sem usar o import getListagem from './MyMixins' nos meus .vue? Porque futuramente eu terei meus .vue 
 em pasta dentro de pasta, aí vai ficar difícil ficar mapeando por " ../../../MyMixins " . Entende? Obrigado!

Comment: Jackson, é mesmo assim, tens de usar caminhos de pastas `../../`. Podes usar `... getListagem ` em vêz de `mixins: [getListagem]`mas para importares esse objeto para o ficheiro tens de usar `import` ou `require`.

Comment: Entendi! Tem como eu deixar esse Mixin global? Onde eu possa acessar ele de qualquer .vue sem utilizar import?

Comment: @Jackson há uma maneira de adicionar mixins globalmente https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin mas não é 100% o que queres, pois só adiciona métodos não corre cada `created`

Comment: Hmm entendi. Vou dar uma estudada nisso. De qualquer maneira, me ajudou bastante! Obrigado!! =)

Comment: @Jackson uma coisa que me ocorreu é que podes ter uma store em cada elemento e depois chamar o método init da store.